# Xavier Initialization for GRU Cells

Tags: initialization, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

Trying to initialize my seq2seq-model. I am using the GRU Cells, but cannot figure out Xavier-Initialization. The code in rnn_cell.py doesnt seem to allow that. Any ideas? Need to do this manually?

thx

Answer (score 2):

The cell's weights are [created using `tf.get_variable()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L901) without specifying an `initializer` parameter. From https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#get_variable:

> If `initializer` is `None` (the default), the default initializer passed in the variable scope will be used.

Therefore, something like the following should work:

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(256)
with tf.variable_scope('RNN', initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()):
    outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, ...)
```